# Module doesn't work in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

I use Orchard CMS and I'm a beginner. I have published it on the host. Now some of my modules don't work. Kwd.Summary module, Vandelay.Meta, etc... is not working. I have to unistall and install these modules again. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are they simply not found or do they crash? Make sure you've included them into your solution before you build Orchard. Also check if they use the same Target framework. Orchard is currently on .Net 4.5.2, so if you're using old modules you may need to change the target framework.

Comment: They are found in my module gallery.but they are not working.I have include the module folder to orchard.web project.Is it correct?

Comment: You should check the logs in `App_Data/Logs` for details. Also make sure you have the [correct folder permissions](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Building-and-deploying-Orchard-from-a-source-code-drop/) set up for your website (#7).